# How to scale layout in android

Tags: android, layout

i've developed an android app, but sometimes users call me and tell me that layout is incorrect to their device. The cause is that android runs on devices with different screen size and density. I try to cover all the type, but when i correct something, other things become incorrect. Damn! Is there a way to create just one layout with one folder of drawable and use something to scale layout in function of different screen size?  Thank you!!
This is an example of my main xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@drawable/sfondo">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:src="@drawable/trovachiavi_contatti" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp" android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"></ImageView>
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/infoButton"
                android:background="@null" android:layout_height="47dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" android:layout_weight="0.25"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:src="@drawable/info_mini"
                android:layout_width="47dp">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutGif"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <trova.chiavi.sd.GIFView
            android:layout_gravity="center" 
            android:layout_height="220dp" android:layout_width="210dp" android:id="@+id/GIFSingle"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"></trova.chiavi.sd.GIFView>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutBanner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/testoBanner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Medium Text"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:maxLines="2"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/Banner"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="144dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/box_codice" 
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
             />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/avvia_cerca"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/chiave"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/testoRicercaSingle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show us an example of one of your xml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using layoutSum and layoutWeight you can resize all content with a percent. I work with linearlayout and this parameters and i do only one layout for every screen size !! :)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes: I'd recommend starting out here: http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/index.html

In particular, under the page "Supporting different screen sizes" note the following:

> By using the "wrap_content" and "match_parent" size values instead of hard-coded sizes, your views either use only the space required for that view or expand to fill the available space, respectively.

It takes a little getting used to the logic, but works very well once you do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the weightSum attribute.
In your parent layout you  put.

```
android:weightSum="100"
```

Then in children views put

view 1

```
android:layout_weight="50"
```

view 2

```
android:layout_weight="50"
```

This will ensure the two views fill the screen. This worked for me.